# How to map many items

Tags: mapping

I'm trying to make a function that maps letters of the alphabet to other letters and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this or do I need to make a dictionary for each individual letter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language but you could convert the character to it's unicode value and do some arithmetic function on to it e.g. in JS

```
var letter = "a";
var code = letter.charCodeAt(0);
// should do some checking to make sure you stay in letter range
code = code + 4;
return String.fromCharCode(code);
```